# Detect commented-out source code (JS)

Tags: javascript, jshint, lint, static-code-analysis, jscs

I need to eliminate the issue working with multiple teams, that developers constantly check in source that contains commented out code. This is a webapp, .html and .js. Unfortunately locked into SVN, so there is nothing preventing the accumulation of code smells in trunk.

We use JSHint and JSCS, netiher support this kind of static code analysis check.
I only found Java related solutions (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356587/tool-for-detecting-commented-out-code) not JavaScript.

What do you think could help? Regexp?

Comment: Regexp can't parse code. Code needs something more advanced like a lexer. What you may give a try is something like [CodeClimate](http://codeclimate.com/), _maybe_.

Comment: Right now I consider writing a plugin for JSCS or JSHint.